# Programmatically change the duplex settings (against the default value) on PCL6 printer

Tags: c#, printing, ms-word, office-interop

I want to change the duplex setting programmatically. But after spending almost a week, still I didn't find the solution.

Currently, I want to just simplex printing (against the default duplex settings).

I tried the almost all the solution. My testing snippet is as follow:

```
Word.Application wordapplication = new Word.Application
{
    Visible = false
};

Word.Document wordDocument = wordapplication.Documents.Add(filePathWithName);
wordapplication.ActivePrinter = printer;
Range range = wordapplication.ActiveDocument.Range(
                        wordapplication.ActiveDocument.Content.Start, 
                        wordapplication.ActiveDocument.Content.End);

//wordapplication.ActiveDocument.Fields.Add(range, WdFieldType.wdFieldPrint, "&l0S", false);     //This also didn't work, people says it works for PCL5 only
wordapplication.ActiveDocument.PrintOut();    ///ManualDuplexPrint: false also didn't work
wordDocument.Close(SaveChanges: false);
wordDocument = null;

// Make sure all of the documents are gone from the queue
while (wordapplication.BackgroundPrintingStatus > 0)
{
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
}

wordapplication.Quit(SaveChanges: false);
wordapplication = null;
```

Comment: Sorry too tired to work out the details, see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/828638/how-to-set-duplex-printing-for-microsoft-word-automation-clients.  You need to change the dmDuplex (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-_devicemodea) property of the struct and use DocumentProperties (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183576(v=vs.85).aspx) to update the spooler.  Hopeful, someone will provide a more detailed answer, if not I'll look at this tomorrow evening.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it's been a long week and I haven't had time to get back to this.  Anyway I went to look up the structs and ran across this:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsod/2012/05/18/how-to-set-duplex-printing-for-microsoft-word-automation-clients-in-c-vb-net/

I believe this is exactly what you are looking for.